# SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

Estoy dando los primeros pasos en programar en esto momento estoy con los condicionales pero con la linea de comando que dejo aquí debajo me da error de sintaxis.

```
if distanciadelaescuela > 30 and cantidaddehermanos > 2 and sueldofamiliar < 15000
```

gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No será que te dejas algo al final?

Comment: Probe dejando y quitando espacios entre las instrucciones, pero me sigue dando error de sintaxis.

Comment: Faltan los dos puntos al final de esa línea. Y la siguiente (con el código a ejecutar si la condición es cierta) debe ir indentada,

Comment: efectivamente eran los dos puntos" : " al final del codigo gracias a ambos por los mensajes

Answer (score 0):

La parte de código, que se ejecuta en caso de que la condición (`if distanciadelaescuela > 30 and cantidaddehermanos > 2 and sueldofamiliar < 15000`) se evalue como cierta, debe ir justo después de la condición separada por dos puntos.

Lo correcto, en tu caso sería:

```
if distanciadelaescuela > 30 and cantidaddehermanos > 2 and sueldofamiliar < 15000:
```

Pero eso no es suficiente ya que la estructura condicional debe contener un mínimo de código, de lo contrario se quejará su interprete:

Definitivamente lo correcto (si todavía no tienes código en tu condicional), sería:

```
if distanciadelaescuela > 30 and cantidaddehermanos > 2 and sueldofamiliar < 15000:
    pass
```